# creating a filter function for UISlider

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view which has a tableview inside and displays a cell with a uislider inside the cell.  Inside CellForRow I attempt to call a function to filter a list of companies by distance inside ListController like so:

```
var listController: ListController!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(sortCellID) as! SortCell

    cell.slider.addTarget(listController, action: #selector(listController.sliderChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    return cell
}
```

The sliderChanged function sits in ListController like so:

```
class ListController: UIViewController {

    func sliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        for index in 0..<self.companies.count {
            if companies[index].distance > sender.value {
                // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

companies is an array of Company() which has the the properties of `latitude` and `longitude`.

I want to filter the companies array based on the value of the slider eg if the slider value is 45 then display all companies with a distance of 0 to 45 in ListController. I'm not sure how correct the function is so far or what else I need to do to make the function do what I want it to do.

Comment: So what problem are you having with your code? (Note that your use of `distanceFromLocation` is likely to be slow and make your slider "jerky".)

Comment: Good point. Think I will create a property to store the distance before filter and then use the distance values. Not a problem with my code as such, just trying to make a function to only show the companies that have a distance from location between 0 and sender.value. Edit: Just changed code which is clearer to read.  I need to put something where `// Do something` is. Although, I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct anyway